# Codeigniter 3 HELPER and DOMPDF PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, helper, dompdf

I have created a helper function and called it in autoload.php
while using in Autoload  Dompdf is Not working and gives error  as "DOMPDF: Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent" after reverting changes its working fine.

```
formsecret_helper.php
function get_form_secret_key() {
  $CI =& get_instance();
  $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  $CI->session->unset_userdata('FORM_SECRET');
  $CI->session->set_userdata('FORM_SECRET', $token);
  return $token;
}
```

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','file','cookie','formsecret');
```

Help me to solve this issue ???